# Clojure: Why let binding doesnt work like for binding?

Tags: clojure

So, I have a `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap` with a key and another `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap` inside, like:

```
{:foo {:bar "bar"}}
```

When I use `for` with the bindings:

```
(for [[key value] {:foo {:bar "bar"}}] do-something)
```

It works fine, but when I try to use `let`, it doesnt works...

```
(let [[key value] {:foo {:bar "bar"}}] do-something)
```

Can somebody help me to understand how let binding works?
Thanks!

Comment: Since both answers so far don't explicitly warn about it: maps are not sorted or ordered by default.  Up to very few entries they are in insert-order, so your example there could work; but be sure your maps only have one entry for that use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with your data:

```
(forv [[key value] {:foo {:bar "bar"}}] ...)
  key   => :foo
  value => {:bar "bar"}


(let [[key value] (first (seq {:foo {:bar "bar"}}))]  ...)
  key   => :foo
  value => {:bar "bar"}
```

You need the `first` to grab just a single `MapEntry` from the sequence.

Note that you don't really need the `seq` if you only want the first one, since `first` internally calls `seq` on its argument:

```
(let [[key value] (first {:foo {:bar "bar"}})]      ; same result
```

Answer (score 3):

With `for` you create a seq from all the `MapEntry`s (let's call them key-vals for now). `for` is list comprehension, not a for-loop, so you are creating a list (lazy seq to be more specific) from binding to successive values on the input.
In `let` you don't bind to successive values, but to just one value, unless you use destructuring in which you can pull out multiple values at the same time from some sequence.

With `let` you would only bind the first and second key-vals to `key` and `value`, but this is not supported, because maps don't have explicit ordering.

However with `seq` you could get two of the key-vals from the map:

```
(let [[a b] (seq {:a 1 :b 2})] [a b])
;;=> [[:a 1] [:b 2]]
```

Comment: Can you help me showing some example on your answer? The docs example is, sometimes, too complex

Comment: Added the example.